# Variável declarada no main não é acessada dentro de outra função

Tags: c

Quando rodo o código abaixo, dá o seguinte erro:

> 'daluno' was not declared in this scope

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Aluno{

    int matricula;
    float p1;
    float p2;
    float p3;
    float t1;
    float t2;
};

void aloca(int N){
    int *pAluno = &daluno;
    pAluno = (int*)malloc(sizeof(daluno)*N);

    if (pAluno==NULL){
        printf("Memoria INSUFICIENTE");
        exit(0);
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf(" Digite a matricula do aluno %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &daluno[i].matricula);
        printf(" Digite a nota da prova 1 do aluno %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d%*c", &daluno[i].p1);
        printf("\n Digite a nota da prova 2 do aluno %d: ",i);
        scanf("%f%*c", &daluno[i].p2);
        printf("\n Digite a nota da prova 3 do aluno %d: ",i);
        scanf("%f%*c", &daluno[i].p3);
        printf("\n Digite a nota do trabalho 1 do aluno %d: ",i);
        scanf("%f%*c", &daluno[i].t1);
        printf("\n Digite a nota do trabalho 2 do aluno %d: ",i);
        scanf("%f%*c", &daluno[i].t2);
    }

    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("matricula: %d prova 1: %f prova 2: %f prova 3: %f trabalho 1: %f trabalho 2: %f\n\n", daluno[i].matricula, daluno[i].p1, daluno[i].p2, daluno[i].p3, daluno[i].t1, daluno[i].t2);
    }
    free(pAluno);
}

int main (){

    struct Aluno daluno;
    int N;

    printf("Digite a quantidade de N alunos: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    aloca (N);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sim, porque ele só esta visível na função main

Comment: Então para eu alocar um vetor dinamicamente tenho que criar uma função?

Comment: Ele é declarado na main, logo só pode ser acessado na main.

Comment: Você tem que colocar ela fora de qualquer função, assim ela se torna uma variável global

Comment: Como você criou a variavel 'daluno' no método main, só o mesmo tem acesso a ela. Para acessar em um nível global, você deve inicializar a variavel fora do método main.

Comment: O main é uma função, e qualquer variável declarada dentro de uma função tem o escopo limitado a função, caso você queira que esta variável seja acessada em qualquer lugar, você tem que declarar ela de forma global, no caso fora de qualquer função.

Comment: Não sei se se encaixar, mas você poderia passar por parâmetro a referencia(ponteiro) dessa variável para ser acessada pela função, e  assim vc alteraria a variável sem declará-la globalmente. Ps: se eu estiver errado eu retiro o comentário....

Answer (score 2):

Este exemplo é similar ao seu problema, onde eu declaro a variável "numero" dentro da função "main", e então chamo a função "mostrarNumero", porem a variável "numero" não esta no escopo de "mostrarNumero", numero só é acessível para a função "main".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mostrarNumero(){
    printf("retultado: %d", numero);
}

int main()
{
    int numero = 1;
    mostrarNumero();
    return 0;
}
```

Contudo se declaramos a variável "numero" fora de qualquer função, ela será declarada de forma global, sendo de escopo global, qualquer função terá acesso a ela, como você pode ver no exemplo abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numero = 1;

void mostrarNumero(){
    printf("retultado: %d", numero);
}

int main()
{
    mostrarNumero();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Error] no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Aluno' and 'int')...Depois de fazer estas alteracoes da esse error...

Comment: Este já não é mais o erro de escopo de variável, acredito que este erro é por causa que você esta tentando fazer um cast de "Aluno" para "int".

Comment: @BrunoGomes Eu acho que é pq `pAluno` deve ser um ponteiro para `struct Aluno`, não `int`. Aliás, dentro de `aloca` vc dá `malloc` e `free` em `pAluno`, e só está usando `daluno` para obter o `sizeof`, mas na verdade vc nem precisa dessa variável, pode removê-la e usar `sizeof(struct Aluno)` direto: https://ideone.com/z2OZmq (faz tempo que não programo decentemente em C, então meu código pode não estar da forma ideal, mas pelo que me lembro, a ideia é essa)

Comment: Ty, deu certo!! '-'

Comment: Por favor, avalie a resposta e marque como respondida ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver este problema declarando a variável como global, ou passando ela como parâmetro da função `aloca()`

Alteração

````
void aloca(int n, Aluno aluno)
{
 //codigo aqui
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Como outros usuários já citaram, você deve declarar a variável de maneira global dessa maneira

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int numero = 1; 
void mostrarNumero(){
printf("retultado: %d", numero);
}
int main() {
mostrarNumero();
return 0; }
```

Assim você conseguirá acessá-la de qualquer função

Ou você pode passar essa variável para a função dessa maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void mostrarNumero(int numero2){
printf("retultado: %d", numero2);
}
int main() {
int numero = 1;
mostrarNumero(numero);
return 0; }
```